# Package custom Flyway release in Quarkus

Tags: flyway, quarkus

The current Quarkus 1.0 release uses Flyway 6, whose CE is not supporting some older database versions.

I tried to exchange in the pom file the default Flyway version of the quarkus-flyway artifact with an older Flyway release, but Quarkus then crashes on startup with some flyway-fluent...-method-not-found exception.

Would there be some easy way to accomplish switching Flyway releases?

Comment: Interesting feedback. Normally people should upgrade, and the Quarkus team will always try to upgrade dependencies to latest compatible version, but you really have a use case for an older build. I think the better solution is to ask the Flyway to reintroduce the features you need in a future version.

Comment: Yes, normally one should update.

Comment: I am afraid the Flyway team won't re-introduce older DB support in the CE version. DB versions they only support in the Enterprise edition - it will probably a financial issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use maven, you can custom flyway verions in pom.xml, like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
        <!-- exclude flyway-core -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>'custom version you want'</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due the build time nature of a lot of Quarkus extensions, changing the version of the dependency may or may not work.